# 403 Forbidden When Trying to Edit Contributions

Tags: civicontribute, drupal

I am running Civi 4.5.5. with Drupal 7. I think this happened after the most recent Drupal update but I cannot be 100% sure when it started.

When trying to edit a donation I get this error "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again." I already followed all the suggestions at http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=28718.0 but none of those worked.

I am getting two JS errors in the console.

```
    GET https:// www.site.org/civicrm/contact/view/contribution?reset=1&
action=update&id=52533&cid=6016&context=contribution&snippet=json 403 
(Forbidden)m.ajaxTransport.send @ js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:136m.extend.ajax @ js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-
OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:136m.each.m.(anonymous function) @ 
js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:136m.extend.getJSON @ 
js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:136$.widget.refresh @ 
js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:1992(anonymous function) @ 
js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:143(anonymous function) @ 
js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:143m.extend.each @ 
js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:134m.fn.m.each @ 
js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:134e.widget.bridge.e.fn.
(anonymous function) @ js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-
OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:143CRM.loadPage @ js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-
OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:2098CRM.loadForm @ js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-
OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:2123CRM.popup @ js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-
OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:2285m.event.dispatch @ js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-
OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:135m.event.add.r.handle @ js_i5iWWCnof58nOcdnrel29-
OfwCcKR_GKWdqmdMYmb9Q.js:135view?reset=1&keyy=469e050135485c6c038247bb3e4b4c9a_7700&cid=6016:1 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.site.org/civicrm/contact
/view/contribution?reset=1&action=update&id=52533&cid=6016&
context=contribution&snippet=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource. Origin 'https:// site.org' is therefore 
not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I thought the problem might be my .htaccess file but I am using the same version of the file from before the Drupal upgrade.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are not spaces in the URLs from the Java console but Stack Exchange will not let me post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to the newest version of CiviCRM and this appears to be resolved.